# I'm unable to mount my USB drive

Tags: usb, mount, disk

I've tried looking up some solutions in here [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RBnF4cs6Bf0) and that did not work as expected. Also, when I typed in `sudo fdisk -l` I received the output instantly with the last part being

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 1.9 GiB, 2001731584 bytes, 3909632 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xedfb5567
```

and when I run `sudo mount /dev/sdb /mnt`, I get:

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb,
missing codepage or helper program, or other error

In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
dmesg | tail or so.
```

Could you provide any help?
Thank you.

Comment: Try using `/dev/sdb1` instead of `/dev/sdb`.  This will mount the partition, not the device.  So use a command like `sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you mount a drive manually, you should mount the parition, and not the device to your mount point.

Using `/dev/sdb` does not tell the `mount` command which partition to use, instead, it's trying to mount the device.

If you use `/dev/sdb1` or `/dev/sdb2` (depending on your partition scheme), that should mount successfully.

Ideally, instead of mounting to `/mnt`, perhaps make a subfolder `sudo mkdir /mnt/usb`

Then finally mount it like this: `sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/usb`

Comment: "mount: special device /dev/sdb1 does not exist" sdb is what had come up when I typed "ls /dev/ | grep sd" with the USB on.

Comment: Are you certain your USB drive has a partition on it?

Comment: Here's a screenshot.. https://s13.postimg.org/dlj9d3h5z/Screenshot_from_2016_11_27_14_05_21.png

Comment: It has no partition on it. Press the '+' button to create one.

Comment: It showed an error at first but it's alright now. Thank you.